# calculate rate of change for multiple columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, missing-data

Attached image is a test data which has missing values for multiple columns.

I need to fill the missing values by doing the rate of change for previous 12 months

[image: test_dataset]

For example, in the attached dataset I have got missing values in rows 23 & 24 for columns `weight_a`, `weight_b`, `weight_c`

- To fill the missing value in row 23, weight_a column I need to do =(B22-B10)/12 + B22
- To fill the missing value in row 24, weight_a column I need to do =(B23-B11)/12 + B23
- To fill the missing value in row 23, weight_b column I need to do =(C22-C10)/12 + C22
- To fill the missing value in row 24, weight_b column I need to do =(C23-C11)/12 + C23

and so on, repeats for the `weight_c` column(and the real data set has a lot of missing values for multiple columns)

How do I write python code to implement this for all missing values in a dataframe?

Comment: The algorithm that you describe is not easy to vectorize as the results for C24 here depend on the previous calculations. Can you accept different interpolation algorithms that fit better to pandas model of computation?

Comment: yes, I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the values then update them manually:

```
result_23=[1,2,3] # calculate real value instead of [1,2,3]
result_24=[1,2,3] # calculate real value instead of [1,2,3]

#Calculate them in this way, Based on what you want
#(df.iloc[22]["B"]-df.iloc[10]["B"]/12)+df.iloc[22]["B"]

df.loc[df.index==23,["weight_a","weight_b","weight_c"]]=result_23
df.loc[df.index==24,["weight_a","weight_b","weight_c"]]=result_24
```